# Как изменить шрифт в Run в Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, шрифты, ide

Когда запускаю проект, у меня между русскими символами большие пробелы, а "слэш" заменяется на знак Йены. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это пофиксить?[image: Сама проблема в изображении]

Comment: судя по скриншоту, у вас винда. скорее всего, в системе нет шрифта. что указано в File \ Settings \ Editor \ Font \ Font? разрешены ли лигатуры?

Comment: Любезный человек снизу уже дал ответ. Я что то протупил, менял шрифт во вкладке Font, а про Console Font совсем забыл)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего какой-то неверный шрифт. В настройках Settings - Editor - Color Scheme - Console Fonts. Здесь можно выбрать цветовую схему консоли, а также шрифт для вывода.

[image: Настройка консоли в Intellij IDEA]